# Terraform isn't uploading aws_api_gateway_request_validator ( Still creating ... )

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm having trouble to add new `aws_api_gateway_request_validator` to an API gateway I've deployed via terraform.
I already have 24 different URI's running on that API Gateway (each of those have a validator , meaning I already have 24 of these running) and when I'm trying to add an additional URI that requires a validator resource , everything besides the validator is getting created( method , integration , integration response , method response) and the validator gets stuck.

** `Adding the validator manually without terraform code works just fine` , so I guess It's not related to AWS limitation , so my question is : `is there a limitation by terraform for this kind of resource that is known ?` or `is there a workaround \ solution for this issue?`

Thanks in advance !

Edit : That's the none working part :

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_request_validator" "example" {
  name                        = "${var.env}example"
  rest_api_id                 = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.saas.id
  validate_request_body       = true
  validate_request_parameters = true
}
```

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "example_method" {
  api_key_required = "false"
  authorization    = "NONE"
  http_method      = "GET"


  request_validator_id = aws_api_gateway_request_validator.example.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.example.id
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.saas.id
}
```

Comment: We need at least a part of the code added to the question.

Comment: I've edited the non working part